# How do I get a batch file to add up numbers in a separate txt file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Given a file with a set of numbers, one per line, like this...

```
1
2
3
```

I want a batch file program which will read the file, add up the numbers, and output the sum. In case of the above input file, the output would be 6.

This is the batch code I have right now:

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set L=1
for /F "delims=" %%a in (hurt.log) do (
  set line=%%a
  echo line !L!: !line!
  set  /a  L=!L!+1
)
pause
set /a "c=%line%+%line%"
echo %c%
pause
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly "add up numbers" means? You need to include a sample input file and the desired output from such an input. Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43210115/edit), do NOT post ample explanations nor code in comments!

Comment: Does the log file contain things other than numbers? Are the numbers all on one line, or are they on separate lines?

Comment: *"I want the code to add up these number: 1 2 3"*.  Okay, the sum of those numbers is `6`.  Problem solved.  (please clarify WTF you are asking)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to output file `hurt.log` with line numbers in front of it?

```
line 1: First Message
line 2: Second Message
line 3: More Data 
[...]
```

Is that correct?

Can you just work from:

```
find /N /V "" hurt.log
```

Its output will look like:

```
[1]First Message
[2]Second Message
[3]More Data 
[...]
```

And is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the file contains only one signed 32-bit integer number per line, this code can be used:

```cmd
set /A "SUM=0"
for /F "usebackq" %%N in ("hurt.log") do set /A "SUM+=%%N"
echo Sum: %SUM%
```

If you want to count the number of lines present in the file, use this:

```cmd
for /F %%N in ('^< "hurt.txt" find /C /V ""') do set /A "COUNT=%%N"
echo %COUNT%
```